# Digital Ocean Droplet Restart Recovery Mode

Tags: linux, digital-ocean

After some issues, I decided to reboot my droplet with `reboot` command. But then My droplet stuck on Recovery Mode, and I haven’t got so much info about Linux.

How can I start my droplet?

It is my droplet’s console screen:

[image: Droplet Console]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Digital Ocean Contol Panel
2. Choose your Droplet
3. Go to Recovery Section
4. Choose Boot from Harddrive
5. Restart your droplet again (with console `reboot` command or from Control Panel Power Tab)

[image: Control Panel]

Comment: This solved my issue of having tremendous fear that digital ocean lost all my files due to restart. It was my fault, I had set up wrong book option lost time ago. Remember once you change it.